# Duration matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-views

Traceback (most recent call last):

````
  File "/home/ahmed/SavannahX/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ahmed/SavannahX/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/SavannahX/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ahmed/SavannahX/app/views.py", line 1352, in yearly_subscription_plans
    duration = Duration.objects.get(name="yearly")
  File "/home/ahmed/SavannahX/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/```
````

django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ahmed/SavannahX/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /yearly/subscriptions/
Exception Value: Duration matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Please post your model and the view which throws the error

Comment: means you don't have `duration` with `name="yearly"` so it throws the exception. So you can either catch exception by putting your code `duration = Duration.objects.get(name="yearly")` inside `try-except` block and throw or raise exception if data does not exists or you can also use other django shortcut function `get_object_or_404` which raises Http404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `.get()` function but it has not found a matching object. This is the danger of using get, it raises an exception if the object isn't found. The `.filter()` function by contrast will just return an empty queryset. You can either:

1. Use the `get_object_or_404` function that returns a 404 HTTP response if the object is not found.

   ```py
   from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

   duration = get_object_or_404(Duration, pk=pk)
   ```

   or
2. Wrap the `get()` in a try/except wrapper:

   ```py
   try:
      Duration.objects.get(name="yearly")
   except:
      # do something else, probably return 404...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> duration = Duration.objects.get(name="yearly")

above code is giving the error as get method raises the "DoesNotExist" if the object is not found and can be handled as below ways

First method

> Duration.objects.filter(name="yearly").first()

Second method

> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
> duration = get_object_or_404(Duration, pk=pk)

Third method

> try:
>     Duration.objects.get(name="yearly")
> except:
>     #**please handle the exception here**